# Ethernet connect fails with LWIP in mbed os

Tags: arm, stm32, ethernet, mbed, lwip

I'm using an mbed enabled board for development, I need to run an Ethernet application on it.

I tried to create a connection by using the following code:

```c
 network = new EthernetInterface();
 network->connect();
 // Show the network address
 const char *ip = network->get_ip_address();
 printf("IP address is: %s\n", ip ? ip : "No IP");
```

Normally it should work, But it fails in the LWIPInteraface class's bringup API at **osSemaphoreAcquire**, returning a timeout error.

```c
if (!netif_is_link_up(&netif)) {
    if (blocking){
        if (osSemaphoreAcquire(linked, 15000) != osOK){
            if (ppp){
                (void) ppp_lwip_disconnect(hw);
            }
            return NSAPI_ERROR_NO_CONNECTION;
        }
    }
}
```

Any reason why I might be getting a timeout from **osSemaphoreAcquire**?
I tried increasing the timeout too but in vain.
If someone could help me with it, would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which target board are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have DHCP enabled on this Ethernet line?

Comment: @yennster it's ublox_c030

Comment: @JanJongboom Yes.